# Determine the function and output from this (very little) assembler code

Tags: function, assembly, x86

`ax` is a register, `shl` means we shift to left by `n` values...
`z` is a memory address and at the beginning it contains the value `4`.

```
mov ax, [z]
shl ax, 3
add ax, [z]
shl ax, 1
mov [q], ax
```

I'd like to know how can we read the function from this code?

So in the first line we put what is in `z` into register `ax`, alright.

Then we shift this value `(4)` to left by `3`, so this operation is basically made: `2^3 * z`

To this we `add` `[z]`, so now we have `2^3 * z + z = 9z`

Now we take `9z` and `shift` it to left by `1`, so we have `9z * 2^1 = 18z`

In the end we take register `ax` and put it into memory address `q`, so we have:

```
q(z) = 18z
```

The task said that z contains value `4`, so in this case the output would be

```
q(4) = 18*4= 72
```

---

**Did I do everything correctly, from explanation to solution?** Please do tell me as I need to do a task like that in the exam.

Comment: Is there some particular part of this you are unsure of?

Comment: I'm asking if it's correct, that's my question.

Comment: Why not asking the TA or the teacher? What value can this question have for this site? Also: why not simply **testing** it. You need to learn how to confirm or reject a hypothesis.

Comment: Because they are on vacation, they just won't reply me (I have already asked other questions and that's what they said). How can I "simply" test it?

Comment: If you need us to tell you that this is correct then you haven't really learned anything.  If we tell you it is correct and you accept it as such, then you really haven't learned anything.  There really isn't a point to this question.

Comment: Alright you smart a$$es, I will return to my maths section now where it's way better and nicer than here. I didn't expect it's going to be well anyway, bye and I wish you guys the worst. Deleting this now so you stop crying, ty. A"yes" or "no" would have been enough, but I can see even this is too much required for you, LOL.

Comment: hm... I was writing answer.

Comment: They are not being smartasses. They are right. They are telling you that it is much better to learn how to verify this by yourself in, say, a debugger than just asking others if it is correct. Write simple code that puts a value in z, check if the result is 18*z and see for yourself. If the value in z is always 4, you can simply put 72 into q directly. People are motivating you to think for yourself, which is quite a Good Thing(tm), not a smartass thing.

Comment: FWIW, my math teachers always taught me how to verify my results. The same should apply to programming.

Comment: I didn't just care about the solution of this code, I have also cared about the way I described it, if this is correct. I have also stated this in my question. A debugger might tell me if the function I have found is correct but won't tell me if my description is correct. So I disagree with you when you say "they are right".

Comment: If you don't care about the solution, then why do you ask others? Your description is correct, but that was not the question. The debugger will tell you the results for various values of z, and that will tell you if you were right or not. It is never bad to learn how to figure out things for yourself.

Comment: I should have said "the solution wasn't the only thing I cared about". It was part of the question and from Ped7g answer I can see that my description WAS NOT correct. Time to get back home, it's very uncomfortable here if you know what I mean.

Comment: @cnmesr You are correct indeed. You are clearly using *z* to denote the input of the function. Saying "what is in *z*" is equivalent to "what is at the address *z*". You are overthinking this all.

Answer (score 0):

> So in the first line we put what is in z into register ax, alright.

No, you put content of memory from value (address) `z` into `ax`.
So `ax` = 4, not `ax` = `z`. In assembly `z` is equivalent to symbol or address, ie. some memory cell label like 12340.

("no" - you probably understand it correctly, I just wanted to emphasize how `[]` is used in x86 intel syntax).

In C `= z` assigns value of variable `z`, and to get the address you have to do `&z`. In Assembly it's the other way around `z` itself is address, `[z]` is content. (at least in NASM syntax, MASM/TASM allows for `mov ax,z` syntax fetching the content, and there you have to write `mov ax,offset z` to get address, but I advice against this mixed usage, where variables are fetched automatically, but accessing memory trough register requires brackets `[rx]`, IMO it's confusing)

Rest is OK.

Comment: masm's 'mov ax, z' without brackets is a pain in the ass, and shouldn't be used imo. It's incompatible, it's implicit, and it's nothing to " make assembler more readable " (what I think was the intention when introducing it)

Comment: I think OP is just using math notation, using *z* to express a generic value at the address *z*.  I would have done the same.

Comment: @TommyLee2k: I actually like MASM's syntax. I don't see an ambiguity. It is clear that the value of the *variable* z is moved to ax.

Comment: @rudy `mov ax, z` in MASM does different things depending on what `z` is. This is not idiomatic in assembly, that should be explicit and simple. Memory accesses are denoted by `[]` and that should always be the case.

Comment: Yeah, I think I was a bit harsh in the answer, as the OP generally got it right, hopefully I managed to add something for him, I wanted just to make sure he gets how the symbols are just addresses in Assembly, losing all other context information from their definition. Thus saying "put *z* into ax" is sort of ambivalent in Assembly, adding "address"/"content" to it makes it more clear.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: what can z be? Whatever it is, `mov ax,z` moves a value from z (the name of a memory location) to ax, just like in high level languages. I find it quite easy to read. Probably because it was the same way in old TASM as well, and it is still that way in Delphi's built-in assembler. And, like in high level languages, if you want the address of z, you must put something in front (& in C, @ in Delphi, offset in MASM).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: If `z` is a constant you defined with `EQU` or `=`, it's a `mov r16, imm16`.  Otherwise it's a `mov r16, [mem]`.  You can't know how an instruction will assemble without looking elsewhere in the program (even if you don't use macros for text substitutions).  I'd rather have the consistency of NASM, even if changing something from an assemble-time constant (EQU) to static data to be loaded from memory means changing the code everywhere it's used.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Never had any problem with this (distinguishing between constants and variables), probably because of how I name variables or constants. Not in higher level languages, not in assembler.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Neither have I, when reading my own code.  Stack Overflow questions, OTOH...